# C#, simplified code to handle both changes and updates of a dependency property

Tags: c#, event-handling, dependency-properties, anonymous-methods, simplify

Obviously, I'm not an expert in C#. I would like to simplify this code by using an anonymous handler, or maybe a lambda, not sure. `ValueHasChanged` is a `PropertyChangedCallback` used when a dp is changed, it ensures the new object will be monitored for update, so that both changes and updates will be processed using the same code: `ProcessNewValue`. The pity here is to create a second handler `ValueHasBeenUpdated` only to call the same method. Is there a possibility to remove the definition of `ValueHasBeenUpdated`? Thanks.

```
private static void ValueHasChanged(
    DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {

    // get instance
    MyClass1 instance = sender as MyClass1;

    // unregister on old object
    if (args.OldValue != null) (args.OldValue as MyClass2).PropertyChanged -=
        instance.ValueHasBeenUpdated;
    // register for updates on new object
    if (args.NewValue != null) (args.NewValue as MyClass2).PropertyChanged +=
        instance.ValueHasBeenUpdated;

    // process new value anyway
    instance.ProcessNewValue();
}

// value has been updated
private void ValueHasBeenUpdated(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

    // just call the actual method that will process it, not elegant...
    ProcessNewValue();
}

// process any new or updated object
private void ProcessNewValue() {...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with doing what you've done. It may seem "inelegant," but it is readable. Readability is more important than elegance. There may be other solutions, but they will all be more confusing for other coders to understand (or for you to understand 6 months from now).

Stick with what you've got.

Comment: Ok, let's go this way... but if someone had a different practice, I'd be interested too. Thanks.